# Mathematical software for Chern-Weil theory

Tags: mathematical-software, dg.differential-geometry

I need to compute curvature forms and Chern-Weil forms for a given metric (in local coordinates) on a vector bundle. Is there are software package that does this? If I manage to compute the derivatives involved is there atleast a package that does the algebra part of it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are such things.See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_software